# Why does Mayoi get embarrassed about this tongue twister?

Tags: japanese-language, monogatari-series

In Bakemonogatari, Mayoi says a tongue-twister that goes

```
「生ムミ、生モメ、生ママモ」
```

("namamumi, namamome, namamamamo") then gets embarrassed because they sound like another word. What's the reference they're making?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Caution: the answer might be NSFW since it contains vulgar words.**

Here is the full dialogue by Araragi and Mayoi:

> 「では、生むみ生もめ生ままもと三回言ってください」
> 「お前が言えてないじゃん」
> 「生もめだなんて、いやらしいですっ！」
> 「言ったのはお前だからな」
> 「生ままもだなんて、いやらしいですっ！」
> 「そのいやらしさは、僕にはわからないが……」
>
> Mayoi: So, say "*namamumi namamome namamamamo*" three times
> Araragi: You can't even say it properly<sup>1</sup>
> Mayoi: *Namamome* is lewd!
> Araragi: It's because you who says it
> Mayoi: *Namamamamo* is lewd!
> Araragi: I don't understand what's lewd with that, though...
>
> <sup>(translated by myself, if there's an official translation of this dialogue, feel free to correct it)</sup>

*Namamumi* doesn't exist in Japanese. The best Kanji representation is 生【なま】無味【むみ】, which means "raw tasteless".

*Namamome* can be represented by 生【なま】揉め【もめ】, which means "bare (breast) grope".

*Namamamamo* is... well, that word also doesn't exist in Japanese, and also meaningless. Even Araragi doesn't understand why Mayoi says that it's lewd.

---

<sup>1</sup>The original tongue twister is [生【なま】麦【むぎ】生【なま】米【ごめ】生【なま】卵【たまご】 (*Namamugi namagome namatamago*)](http://www.punipunijapan.com/hayakuchi-kotoba-namamugi/), which means "raw wheat, raw rice, raw egg". The one that Mayoi says is when all the consonants are changed to "*m*" (except the "*n*" in "*nama*"). This is to simulate the pronunciation by very young child (e.g. toddler) when their ability to speak is not well-developed yet.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not surprised it's NSFW (knowing this show). Thanks for the detailed answer!